# Drop box is not syncing in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, dropbox

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

I downloaded dropbox yesterday using  [this link](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-dropbox-ubuntu/).

I did everything mentioned in that but I did not see below message.

> Output This computer isn't linked to any Dropbox account... Please
>   visit
>   https://www.dropbox.com/cli_link_nonce?nonce=35ff549233f01a5d4e699826b0ab6ffb
>   to link this device.

It got installed and I see a dropbox folder in Home folder of my computer.

Now, I do not think it is syncing. Even if I delete some files from [dropbox page](https://www.dropbox.com/home),  I do not see it change anything in my computers Dropbo folder.

Can some one help me to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using 18.04 the best way to install Dropbox is from the Ubuntu Software Center. This was not available in earlier versions - in 16.04 we had to install from the command line which was a bit of a task to get right.

If you have set the left <kbd>Super</kbd> key as the `Overview Shortcut` (in Tweaks) press it to get to the search box and start typing `gnome` and you will be presented with the Ubuntu Software icon which you can select.

[image]

This makes it very easy to install and I have successfully done this a number of times on 18.04 and each time it has set up everything completely perfectly.

You should already have the Gnome Software facility installed on your system.

[image]

Installing it from the terminal is a much more complicated affair. You may need to uninstall what you have done so far in order to get a 'clean' install from the USC

Comment: It worked for me.. I did not uninstall what I have done before installing from software centre.. How do I do that?

Comment: Does it not create a problem if I do not uninstall? I can do it all now if you can say how to do....

Comment: I don't see that a problem will be created as it now stands. I only suggested uninstalling if getting it from the USC was a problem - which it is clearly not. Thanks for the upvote and accepting the answer. Dropbox is a useful tool made very simple by Ubuntu.

Comment: for those of you coming to this page unable to find a solution, this worked for me: I went to terminal and typed `dropbox stop` and then `dropbox start`. Then the terminal indicated something was wrong and gave me a command to fix the problem. I copy and pasted this command in the terminal, restarted dropbox, and then dropbox started functioning again. This was the command: `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p`

Comment: @jtorca This has worked for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact problem on a new install of 18.04 & new install of Dropbox. As mentioned in a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166543/drop-box-is-not-syncing-in-ubuntu-18-04-3-lts/1241183#comment2051069_1166545) on the other answer, executing the following commands in terminal solved the problem. First,

```
dropbox stop
```

followed by

```
dropbox start
```

This command prompted an error message, which provides a new set of commands for the terminal:

```
Unable to monitor entire Dropbox folder hierarchy. Please run "echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p" and restart Dropbox to fix the problem.
```

So I ran the command in terminal mentioned in the error message (repeated below)

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p
```

And then restarted dropbox and the problem was fixed.

Comment: Worked for me, after an upgrade to ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Worked om Ubuntu 18.04 using on caja-dropbox.